# Network hangs using chrome with dev tools on MacMini late 2014

Tags: laravel, google-chrome, networking, mamp

I am working at a project with laravel on my machine, I am using MAMP for local hosting and Chrome for testing etc. Sometimes when I have the developer tools open in Chrome and I refresh a page the network (WAN) hangs. I am connected through ethernet with powerlines, I am positive that the router is not resetting the connection and the powerlines are working. Any clue

Answer (score 0):

Honestly it is hard to tell.

I have noticed my site hanging on my local environment occasionally for a variety of reasons.

- A mixture of secure and non-secure content http and https calls.
- Fonts, JavaScript, CSS, etc. that is housed on a CDN.

If you look at the console and network tab when you are loading the site, it might give you some clues as to what items are blocked or are taking a long time to load.

Good luck.

Comment: yes it hangs looking for stuff on a CDN but the problem is the whole network connection hangs

Comment: I would try pulling everything into your local environment to see if that fixes the issue. If not, you have a network issue. If so, then add the cdn items back one by one and see which one causes the slow down.

Comment: Interestingly this doesn't happen with firefox

Comment: I think it has to do with the security surrounding chrome's dev tools. Fonts coming from a https server were slowing my chrome down a while back only in local debug mode.